# inserting values in custom tables while registering in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I am working on a project in WordPress where i need to make 5 different tables. I want to insert data in those tables accordingly while the user registers on my website. I am using theme my login for that and the data which I want to be entered will be generated accordingly. I know that I have to use wpdb commands to insert data but I don't know in what file I need to write my codes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to add the code in the functions.php file of the theme.

You can use a 'hook' to hook into a function that is happening somewhere behind the scenes in WordPress. The hook you will need to use is the user_register hook.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/user_register

Quick note. When editing code in the functions.php file of the theme you should make sure you use a child theme so that when you update your theme you don't overwrite the changes you have made.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Here is the function that you use to hook the user registering.

```
<?php

    add_action( 'user_register', 'mytheme_registration_save', 10, 1 );

    function mytheme_registration_save( $user_id ) {

        if ( isset( $_POST['first_name'] ) ) {
            // Custom commands
        }

    }

?>
```

Then you can use the wpdb insert to add additional data to other tables.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/insert/

Your question wasn't very specific so I will try to give you a more generic answer.

```
<?php

    $wpdb->insert('wp_submitted_form', array(
        'name' => 'John',
        'email' => 'john@gmail.com',
        'phone' => '123456768',
    ));

?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. just want to know that i copy the above wpdb->insert code and i add it to the if block of "//custom command" and copy everything and put it in functions.php of child theme?